# How to know super class designated initializers?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer

I am in need of subclassing, compiler warning says "Must call a designated initializer of the superclass", but i can not find them, where should i look for designated initializers?, i would like to know where to look for them independent of the class for future subclassing.

code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class JBSOSLongGestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer {

    init() {

        super.init()

        self.allowableMovement = 40
        self.minimumPressDuration = 5
        self.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        self.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
    }

}
```

Comment: Why did you roll back my edit?  Your question title is unclear, I cleaned up your post.

Comment: @JAL ok, fixed it myself, the point was not about this concrete case or class, but to know where to search for in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UILongPressGestureRecognizer` inherits from `UIGestureRecognizer`.  The designated initializer for `UIGestureRecognizer` is `public init(target: AnyObject?, action: Selector)`.

Override `init(target: AnyObject?, action: Selector)` instead of `init()`.

I found the designated initializer by jumping to the definition of `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`.  I didn't see an initializer there, but I did see that it was a subclass of `UIGestureRecognizer`.  Stepping into the `UIGestureRecognizer` declaration revealed the public initializer.

This information is also available in the Apple API docs.  The documentation will say *Designated Initializer* next to the designated initializer.

[UIGestureRecognizer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/)

Comment: as the question says, i would like to know where to see each class designated initializer besides this concrete case, where did you get that designated initializer from?

Comment: @JuanPabloBoeroAlvarez edited my answer to show my process of finding the initializer.

Comment: ok, got it working, check the code to see what was missing from your answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`UILongPressGestureRecognizer` is a concrete subclass of `UIGestureRecognizer`. So while you can subclass it using the method @JAL provided it is not intended to be subclassed.

In your code it doesn't seem like you are adding any functionality to your `JBSOSLongGestureRecognizer`, why not just use `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` and configure it with the values you want?